# Show that $A_{ij}=\langle Ae_j,e_i\rangle$ is unique.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ and $\{e_i\}$ be an orthonormal basis.
I'm trying to show that $A_{ij}=\langle Ae_{j},e_i\rangle$ is unique.

So first let $A'_{ij}\in\mathbb{C}$ and $Ax=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}A'_{ij}\langle x,e_j\rangle ) e_i$ for $x\in\mathcal{H}$. I'm trying to prove this by contradiction. How can I proceed to do so?

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by unique ? Unique vs. what?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net In a sense that if $A'_{ij}$ and $Ax$ is as described, it is in fact $A_{ij}=A'_{ij}$

Answer (score 0):

Simply observe that $$Ae_l=\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^\infty A_{ij}'\langle e_l,e_j\rangle e_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_{il}'e_i,$$ and so $$A_{kl}=\langle Ae_l,e_k\rangle=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty A_{il}'\langle e_i,e_k\rangle=A_{kl}',$$ since $\langle e_l,e_j\rangle=\delta_{lj}$ and $\langle e_i,e_k\rangle=\delta_{ik}.$

Comment: How does the first line hold? And what is $\delta$?

Comment: The first line holds because $\langle e_l,e_j\rangle=\delta_{lj}$. That means that it equals $1$ when $l=j$ and $0$ otherwise. In particular, the sum over $j$ becomes a single term.

Comment: It's called the Kronecker delta: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta.